# Communication between 2 arduinos

Tags: arduino

I am working with Arduino yun, and I would like to know how can I access sensor values from one arduino using another arduino. Which ways of comunication they are between arduinos? Can I access data from another arduino through wireless? Do I need additional hardware to accomplish this, or its possible with just two arduinos and one computer?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Read here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more information about how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable question.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways, without any external hardware you have :

- [SPI](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SPI)
- [I2C](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Wire)
- [Serial communication/UART](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Serial)

Serial is the easiest to use among these 3.

And for any other kind of communication you will require external hardware, so if you want to go wireless, then you have cheap RF modules, XBee, etc..

That said that's more appropriate question for Arduino SE site ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. Arduinos, depending on the model, can usually communicate via SPI, I2C, etc. Both Arduinos can send and receive data via SPI, for example, so you can hook them up to each other.

It also depends on the type of sensor data you have as well as how many open pins you have: if you really wanted to, you could set 8 bits of data to 8 different pins, and simply connect those pins to 8 pins on the receiving Arduino. That's a rather barbaric way to do it considering you have SPI at your disposal, though.

Comment: It's between 2 arduinos :) not between arduino and sensor, and btw it's hard for him to invent 8 pin communication protocol, it's even the waste of pins, because UART uses only 2 :) And most of Atmega chips support SPI,I2C, and UART

Comment: Two Arduinos will support SPI between one another. He stated that he wants to "access sensor values from one arduino using another arduino", so that's why I mentioned sensor data. I also mentioned (and agree) that using 8 pins is a waste. Just trying to drive home the point that he has many options available.

Answer (score 0):

Check this page. https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/MasterWriter

I used the I2C to trigger sound from on one arduino and play it on the other. There was no noticeable delay. If you want to stream a lot of data then SPI should be used.